# Can SSL be used with gRPC in a C# .NET Framework service application?

Tags: c#, .net, grpc

I have a sever written in C# using the .NET Framework and running as a Windows service. It communicates via gRPC to clients written in Unity. Is it possible to use SSL to secure the connection? Is HTTP/2 required which is not supported by the .NET Framework?

Comment: Have you seen [this turorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/troubleshoot?view=aspnetcore-3.1)?

Comment: Yes. It mostly talks about .NET Core. I've had a couple of engineers trying to get it to work for a week without success. Most online resources talk about using [grpc-dotnet](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet) which doesn't support the .NET Framework